# ReadFile winapi fails on reading from virtual box shared folder. GetLastError is throwing the error 183

Tags: c++, winapi, readfile

I'm calling ReadFile winapi function to read some data from virtualbox shated folder. ReadFile failes. GetLastError is throwing the 183 error code 'Cannot create a file when that file already exists'.
Sometimes it happens on vmware shared folders.

My code example

```
bool ret = ReadFile(hFile, buf, size, &bytesRead, nullptr);
if (ret == FALSE)
{
    logger << L"err: " + ToString(GetLastError());
}

//out:
//err: 183
```

Can anyone help me with strange error?

Comment: Getting a "cannot create file" error from ReadFile() can only be classified as a virtual error.  Improve your error reporting so you can distinguish CreateFile errors from ReadFile errors.

Comment: After CreateFile i'm getting 0 error code.

Comment: Can we see the code from `CreateFile` please?  Error code 183 doesn't make sense from `ReadFile()`

Answer (score -1):

First off, your code snippet is a little...wonky. ReadFile returns a BOOL (a Microsoft-defined type that existed in the days before C had 'bool'). You're then assigning that to a C-style bool, and then comparing that bool to the MS constant 'FALSE'. As written it is NOT wrong, but it's a bad idea to switch between the various forms of boolean unnecessarily, as it tends to make it harder to see the actual sense of the test.

Second, I suspect that this code is NOT exactly the code that is failing!

I say this because I CAN produce the described behavior by simply inverting the sense of the test on the ReadFile. That is, if you check GetLastError when ReadFile returns true, it will (on my machine, today, when reading a serial port) give error 183! I therefore suspect that in the real code the OP has actually muffed the boolean test somehow (as I did earlier in the day), thus causing the apparent bogus ReadFile error.

My solution to this is to re-write the test to be as simple as possible, using as few forms of boolean as possible, in order to give the best chance of not muffing the test.

If you change the code to this (presuming you don't actually need the ReadFile return value elsewhere):

```
if (!ReadFile(hFile, buf, size, &bytesRead, nullptr))
{
    DWORD err = GetLastError();
    logger << L"err: " + ToString(err);
}
```

That code makes it easy to see the sense of the test in question, and reduces the possibility of writing the test wrong.

If you really need to keep 'ret', then do this:

```
BOOL ret = ReadFile(hFile, buf, size, &bytesRead, nullptr);
if (!ret)
{
    DWORD err = GetLastError();
    logger << L"err: " + ToString(err);
}
```

In both cases you'll note that I pulled the GetLastError call out of the log line. That's to make sure that nothing can possibly happen in between the call to ReadFile and the call to GetLastError.

EDIT: Revised to clarify my opinions. Original version didn't state that I thought OP posted different code than was failing.

Comment: Even if I like your love for strict type safety, I don't think that will make a difference in this case: `BOOL` is `int` and it is converted to a `bool`, so `==0 -> false; !=0 -> true`. Then it is compared to `FALSE`, that is 0: `false==0 -> true; true==0 -> false`. All as expected.

Comment: Converting between `int`, `bool`, and `BOOL` back and forth is all in a days work for any Win32 developer. Unfortunate, but true.

Comment: @rodrigo - revised to state that posted code is OK, but that I think the OP didn't post the actual failing code.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi - I've re-worked my answer to state that I think the OP didn't actually post the failing code, and that I think if he takes the real code and simplifies it, he'll find the bug. I stand by, however, the label 'wonky' for code that compares a boolean to the integer constant FALSE. It's correct, but it's bad coding practice.